# Spark-Hive error, how I can resolve?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I have tried to write a simple code for accessing Hive tables using SparkSql:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                                 .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                                 .master("local[*]")
                                 .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
                                 .enableHiveSupport()
                                 .getOrCreate();

try{
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select survey_response_value from health");
    df.show();
} catch (Exception AnalysisException) {
    System.out.print("\nTable is not found\n");
}
```

I ran this particular program many times on my system and it was running fine. But all of a sudden it stop working and started giving errors.
Here is the complete list of error and trace:
https://justpaste.it/13w2r
I am using IntelliJ.

I have not done anything with the dependencies or with the code. So I do not understand what made the code do not work. And how I can get rid of it?  Kindly, help me.
Here is the problem:

```
17:22:50.442 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 0 from show at hivespark.java:29
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
    at sparky.hivespark.main(hivespark.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.1
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:651)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 25 more
17:22:50.612 [Thread-2] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Could you put build file with scope, concretely faster-xml dependecy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using SBT then add ....

Here I mentioned 2.8.x you can also mention any version which is compatible in your environment above 2.5

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
```

if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is there anything else you are facing after this ? pls respond.